# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child - when trying async on page.tsx in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, next.js

I am trying to use async on `page.tsx` in nextjs 13 "app router" approach and keep gettin this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Here's the code example:

```
const AsyncFunc = async () => {
    // reason i use async is because i have await on the http request
    const posts = await fetchPosts();

    return <div>async print posts...</div>
}

export default function Sidebar() {
    return <div>sidebar <AsyncFunc/></div> // error...
}
```

Comment: An `async function` returns a `Promise` object, so the result can't be used as a React Child

Comment: To do async processing, one possible way is to use `useState`, and then `useEffect` or other similar functions to update the component.

Comment: Since you're using next 13, you don't need to use useState and useEffect as @qrsngky suggested. Take a look at https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components and https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I end up finding the answer, my problem was

Component in client:

```
"use client" // its ok to use use client. this component is for FE!
export default function SomeFrontEndComponent() {
    useEffect(() => {
        // usage of useEffect! its a client behaviour!
    }, []);

    return (<div className="main">
        <h1>Sub component = its fe behaviour</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

component in server side (which is async with server side fetch):

```
// profile/page.tsx entity file
// it's ok to do a async fetch, this is possible both on front end and backend:
async function fetchData(promptslug:string) { 
    let res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/data`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
    });

    if(!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Fail fetch');
    }

    return res.json();
}


// usage of async on a page component
export default async function Page() {
    const data = await fetchData();

    return (<div className="main">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

code taken from [here](https://lior-amsalem.hashnode.dev/nextjs-error-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise-if-you-meant-to-render-a-collection-of-children-use-an-array-instead)

Comment: This is not working for me, even though I am on typescript 5.1.6 and @types/react 18.2.20. React throws the same error at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

don't think you can have async components in React since rendering is synchronous. Here you can use state and useEffect.

```
const AsynCfun = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAndSetData = async () => {
      const data = await fetchPosts();
      // do whatever needs to be done on data
      setData(data);
    };
    fetchAndSetData();
  });

  return <div>async print posts...</div>;
};
```

Then can render as normal in sidebar. One thing is useEffect callback cannot be async directly so you have to create async function and perform any stateful operations within as shown above.

Hope it helps,
Best

Comment: There are no async components in regular React, but there are for "React Server Components" in next JS. But then there are some restrictions for what can go into a server component and what cannot (see the links in the comments above).

Comment: thanks for your comment, but your code is client side only. and i was looking for server side and client side seperation